# Liquibase sql execution using changelog.xml file included with main.sql

Tags: liquibase-sql

I am executing a main.sql file having 2 sub sql files inside main.sql file as createtable1.sql and createtable2.sql. when i am executing using liquibase getting error as invalid format

[image: 1]

```
--liquibase formatted SQL
--changeset dev:1 runOnChange:true splitStatements:true stripComments:false runAlways:false  labels:new-label context:example-context
--comment: For main SQL file

@createtable2.sql
/
@createtable3.sql
/

commit
/
```

Comment: Please don't share code/errors as images. It makes it harder for people to help you resolve the issue. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I added the code properly in an edit to your OP and I noticed that there's an extra space before one of the parameters on the changeset line.  If you can please add the full text of the exact error you're seeing we can take a look, but just for grins, try removing that extra space and see if it resolves the issue for you.